# Client_Server two .cs in one project issue

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, sockets, client-server

I have to get started with Client Server Communication for my application. To get started, I want to connect to local host.

Here's the code:

**Server**

```
public class serv 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        try 
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); //use local m/c IP address, and use the same    in the client

            /* Initializes the Listener */
            TcpListener myList=new TcpListener(ipAd,1025);

            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */       
            myList.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 1025..."); 
            Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" + myList.LocalEndpoint );
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

            Socket s=myList.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from "+s.RemoteEndPoint);

            byte[] b=new byte[100];
            int k=s.Receive(b);
            Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
            for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

            ASCIIEncoding asen=new ASCIIEncoding();
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
            Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");

            /* clean up */          
            s.Close();
            myList.Stop();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }   
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
public class clnt 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        try 
        {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

            tcpclnt.Connect("127.0.0.1",1025); // use the ipaddress as in the server program

            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

            String str=Console.ReadLine();
            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen= new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] ba=asen.GetBytes(str);
            Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

            stm.Write(ba,0,ba.Length);

            byte[] bb=new byte[100];
            int k=stm.Read(bb,0,100);

            for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

            tcpclnt.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

The Project has two `Main()` functions. So,to avoid conflict i set `serv.cs` as `StartupObject` but resulted in no-access to client's console window to send message.

1).**How to use /run such programs on local host?**

I actually needed a good starting point for using Sockets but most of the apps available on net are either quite obsolete or more advanced.I already had worked on Sockets using *Linux* but new to this environment.

2).**Any good example other than this?**

I have already googled up alot but SO is my last hope!.The projects on CodeProject are using UI and a simple Console app is needed for startup.

Comment: You need to create two projects within one solution. One project should contain the server. The other project should contain the client.

Comment: You should check out WCF services. I am not sure what the purpose your program is going to serve is but from your code it seems like it is exactly what you need because it let's you call methods through the network and basically does all the work for you at the low(not necessarily) price of some configuration. I recommend you to read up on that before continuing with your present approach.

Comment: My app is file sharing on  a local network@Phoenix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than your code is not necessary. 
Do you start both projects?
You have to start the server first, and then the client, so the client can connect to the waiting server.

Comment: Is there any method to keep both console windows open during the whole opeartions i.e. the console shown after server run be still after client run but with a new console with a client run?